# Eslint rules for json files

Tags: json, eslint, prettier

I try to implement eslint rules for json files, like I have rule :
"quotes": ["error", "single"]
but I don't want this rule to concern json files, only ts/tsx/js/jsx files. how can I specify rules for special formats?

I try to remove json format from src but it's not a solution

Answer (score 0):

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface#-ext suggests:

```
# Use both .js and .ts
npx eslint . --ext .js --ext .ts

# Also use both .js and .ts
npx eslint . --ext .js,.ts
```

so in your case:

```
npx eslint ./src --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify ESLint rules for specific file formats, you can use the `overrides` field in your ESLint configuration file (.eslintrc.js, .eslintrc.json, or eslintConfig in package.json).

Here's how you can specify rules for TypeScript/JavaScript files and exclude JSON files:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "quotes": ["error", "single"]
        // Add other rules specific to TypeScript/JavaScript files
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.json"],
      "rules": {
        // Override rules for JSON files if needed
        // You can set rules to "off" or "warn" if you don't want them to apply to JSON files
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above configuration:

The first `overrides` block applies rules to TypeScript/JavaScript files (*.ts, *.tsx, *.js, *.jsx).

The second `overrides` block applies rules to JSON files (*.json).

Inside each `overrides` block, you can specify rules that apply only to the files matching the specified patterns. You can set rules to "off" or "warn" if you want to disable them or change their severity level for specific file formats.

Make sure to adjust the patterns ("*.ts", "*.tsx", etc.) to match the file extensions you're using in your project.